# How to set algorithms for PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions webauthn-lib 4.7?

Tags: php, webauthn

I'm trying to get started with webauthn-lib 4.7 using [the documentation](https://webauthn-doc.spomky-labs.com/pure-php/authenticator-registration).

Based on the docs, I came up with this code:

```
$user_entity = new PublicKeyCredentialUserEntity($user->getAccountName(), $user->id(), $user->getDisplayName());

$rp_entity = PublicKeyCredentialRpEntity::create('My app', 'example.com', null);

$challenge = random_bytes(16);

$credential_options = PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions::create(
  $rp_entity,
  $user_entity,
  $challenge,
  // ['excludeCredentials', $exclude_credentials]
);
```

But PHPStorm is warning me:

`Required parameter '$pubKeyCredParams' missing`

The documentation doesn't have an example of `$pubKeyCredParams`, but it does say:

> A list of supported public key parameters i.e. an algorithm list (at
> least one)

What format should this list take?  Are these supposed to be the same as the [algorithms supplied to the Algorithm Manager](https://webauthn-doc.spomky-labs.com/pure-php/the-hard-way#algorithm-manager)?

For reference, those algorithms are:

```
use Cose\Algorithm\Manager;
use Cose\Algorithm\Signature\ECDSA\ES256;
use Cose\Algorithm\Signature\RSA\RS256;

$algorithmManager = Manager::create()
    ->add(
        ES256::create(),
        RS256::create()
    )
;
```

But how do I format them into something that `PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions()` will accept?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CredentialsContainer/create#pubkeycredparams also the discussion in https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1757 might give you an idea of what algorithms you should add support for.

Comment: @Chris Thanks.  I edited the question.  I'm happy to use the algorithms the documentation suggests, but I don't understand how to format them so that the function will accept them as an argument.

Comment: Looks like you can add the algorithm-manager to the options with `$credential_options->addAlgorithmManager($algorithmManager);` but that comes from an AI generated response, so it might be wrong ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was explained in the previous versions of the documentation, but removed in 4.7 without clarification.
Now you can pass an empty array and the algorithm list will be ES256 and RS256 by default.

This list shall contain `Webauthn\PublicKeyCredentialParameters` objects that refer to a COSE algorithm identifier.

```php
use Cose\Algorithms;
use Webauthn\PublicKeyCredentialParameters;

$publicKeyCredentialParametersList = [
    PublicKeyCredentialParameters::create('public-key', Algorithms::COSE_ALGORITHM_ES256),
    PublicKeyCredentialParameters::create('public-key', Algorithms::COSE_ALGORITHM_RS256),
];
```